# Draw Graph inside word document using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graph, ms-word

I'm trying to draw graph inside word document using VB.net. 
I'm having the X-axis and Y-axis points and I need to draw a line graph according to these points.

Also next time when I run this tool and pass the document file, the tool is supposed to read the previous data points and draw another graph with the appended data of the previous points.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Great spec.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hey Sam, I've tried the following link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383 but I found that they are using Static chart ClassType:="MSGraph.Chart.8" however I need to insert some points and values not a static one like that :)